# Cannot install IDSwakeup due to LibNet

Tags: networking

So I did download IDSwakeup and installed libnet and hping3 from ubuntu repositories. When I try to "make" IDSwakeup I get the following error:

```
gcc  -o iwu iwu.o -lnet ; \

iwu.o: In function `main':
iwu.c:(.text.startup+0x148): undefined reference to `libnet_open_raw_sock'
iwu.c:(.text.startup+0x26b): undefined reference to `libnet_write_ip'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [iwu] Error 1
```

What I am doing wrong? I tried to reinstall libnet several times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the version of libnet that you are using. The error that you are getting is that in the library that you are trying to link the symbols libnet_open_raw_sock and libnet_write_ip are missing.

IDSWakeup uses version 1.0 of libnet which you can find here:

http://packetfactory.openwall.net/libnet/dist/deprecated/libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz

If you visit the most recent version of the libnet maintainer (in github) you'll see that he calls out migration steps to 1.1 which specifically calls for the removal of certain calls:

https://github.com/sam-github/libnet/blob/master/libnet/doc/MIGRATION

```
MIGRATING YOUR CODE TO LIBNET 1.1 AND QUICKSTART

Using Libnet 1.1 you will find it MUCH simpler to build and write packets
than before.  Instead of the previous five steps (initialize memory,
initialize network, build packet, do checksums, write packet) there are
now only three steps (initialize library, build packet, write packet).  
In order to port your existing code, you will mainly be REMOVING 
function calls and variables.

1) Start with code removal:

    - Remove all calls to libnet_init_packet() / packet malloc()ing and
      all associated variables.
    - Remove all calls to libnet_open_raw_sock() / libnet_open_link_layer()
      and all associated variables.
    - Remove all calls to libnet_do_checksum() and all associated
      variables.
```

To get IDSWakeup working on Ubuntu 14.04 do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --yes build-essential autoconf libtool make

wget http://packetfactory.openwall.net/libnet/dist/deprecated/libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz -O libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz 
tar xvf libnet-1.0.2a.tar.gz
cd Libnet-1.0.2a
./configure
sudo make install
cd ..

wget http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/idswakeup/download/IDSwakeup-1.0.tgz -O IDSwakeup-1.0.tgz
tar xvf IDSwakeup-1.0.tgz
cd IDSwakeup-1.0
make
cd ..
```

Finally to run IDSWakeup against a machine at 192.168.0.6 do the following:

```
cd IDSwakeup-1.0
sudo ./IDSwakeup 0 192.168.0.6 1 1
```

You should see output like this:

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
-  IDSwakeup : false positive generator               -
-  Stephane Aubert                                    -
-  Herv? Schauer Consultants (c) 2000                 -
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

  src_addr:0  dst_addr:192.168.0.6  nb:1   ttl:1 

  sending : teardrop ...
  sending : land ...
  sending : get_phf ...
  sending : bind_version ...
  sending : get_phf_syn_ack_get ...
  sending : ping_of_death ...
  sending : syndrop ...
  sending : newtear ...
  sending : X11 ...
  sending : SMBnegprot ...
  sending : smtp_expn_root ...
  sending : finger_redirect ...
  sending : ftp_cwd_root ...
  sending : ftp_port ...
  sending : trin00_pong ...
  sending : back_orifice ...
  sending : msadcs ...
```